i want to match my data.json file with the image dataset i have
I have a data.json file and an image dataset (all the images in one file),
I want to match them and separate them into folders then train and test etc.
I'll give 3 examples of what the json file contains:
{
    "iskZwzri42zg0vdZGVRJYIP25svQgQLc.jpeg": {
        "cooling": false,
        "pollen": false,
        "varroa": false,
        "wasps": true
    },
    "l01Y3euvXnrq1XdlpA8oBVRc3uaXDKVo.jpeg": {
        "cooling": false,
        "pollen": true,
        "varroa": false,
        "wasps": false
    },
    "KMM0R4UV5leP51apLk4VNkLJMrudWdF1.jpeg": {
        "cooling": false,
        "pollen": true,
        "varroa": false,
        "wasps": false
    } 

and that's the case for 7000+ images with different Boolean values
Is it possible to separate them into folders or do i need to do something else entirely, if so how do i train and test, i have also reviewed some of the answers to similar questions but the json files were different and didn't really help with what i'm looking for.
